# Old house with no neutral/no ground switches

Tags: power-supply, power, short-circuit

So, I want to put some small monitor near the door. The only thing I have there is a simple on/off switch of old, with no ground and no neutral.
Since this switch is 95% of the time off, the voltage on the terminals is 110VAC.
So I thought of using this to drive a Mean Well AC/DC MPM05-5 AC/DC power supply and charge a small battery *set as a backup*. Basically if the switch is ON the battery will power the monitor and if OFF it will be powered from the AC. Seeing 95% of the time its off a small battery will do the trick.

However! When the switch is turned ON, the Input side of the AC/DC power supply is suddenly shorted, and I assume the EMI filter at the AC/DC has an inductor. Am I going to have a problem?
[image]

Comment: Illegal in most countries. You will have voltage division between your power supply and the bulb, which may glow faintly. Call an electrician to add a neutral  and ground wire and an outlet where you need it.

Comment: Possibly doable by using diodes for bulb and supply. Fwd (say) diode in series with meanwell and across bub. Reverse diode tyriug switch and feeding bulb. Capacitors etc to maintain voltage in half cycle off period in each case. Peay (or design) :-).